# How to tchart x-axis date and time control?

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I'm use Teechart version .Net & VS2005.

X-axis of the graph type of date and time, Y-axis was added to the line Series.

I do not want to represent the null value of the x-axis date and time.

---------data table---------------------

[image]

----- Teechart x-axis display -----------

[image]

The red line is cursor tool. I set the value of the 'follow mouse = true'. 
Cursor tool indicates to text a date and time value of x-axis. shows the time not in the data table. Following values ​​18:23:49 shows the 18:23:50 example. I want to express to the x-axis value for date and time of the data table.

```
my code:

private void TeeChartSet()
{
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line line = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line();
TChart1.Series.Add(line);
line.XValues.DateTime = true;
TChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = Steema.TeeChart.Utils.DateTimeStep[(int)Steema.TeeChart.DateTimeSteps.OneSecond];
line.Stairs = true;            

TChart1.Series[i].XValues.DataMember = "SetTime";
TChart1.Series[i].YValues.DataMember = "Park Brk Pres Sw1";
TChart1.Series[i].DataSource = Datatable;

TChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelStyle.PointValue;
}

private void cursor1_Change(object sender, CursorChangeEventArgs e)
{
    TChart1.Invalidate();
    DateTime Time = DateTime.FromOADate(e.XValue);
    sli_CursorTime.Text = "Cursor Time : " + Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}

private void MakeDt() //Make datatable Sample Code
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SetTime");
    dt.Columns.Add("Park Brk Pres Sw1");

    DataRow row;


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["SetTime"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(i * 5);
        row["Park Brk Pres Sw1"] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Could you attach your DataValues(DataTable), because we can work with your exactly data? Thanks,

Comment: Add to make data table sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your extra information, it has been very useful for us. I have made a code, because you can use it to solve your problem. To make code, I have used annotation tool, cursor tool and series line, where only is shown the values of series point in annotation tool. Also I have changed the DateTimeFormat of series. I have added a line of code to export data values as excel format because you can see the results to change DateTimeFormat and it works in your correct way.

```
 Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool cursorTool1;
 private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.Annotation ann;
 private double xval;
 private void InitializeChart()
 {
     tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
     //Tools
     cursorTool1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool(tChart1.Chart);
     cursorTool1.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorToolStyles.Vertical;
    // cursorTool1.Pen.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
     cursorTool1.FollowMouse = true;

   //  cursorTool1.OriginalCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
     ann = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.Annotation(tChart1.Chart);
     ann.Shape.Pen.Visible = false;
     ann.Shape.Shadow.Visible = false;
     ann.Shape.ShapeStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.TextShapeStyle.RoundRectangle;
     //Series
     Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line line1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line(tChart1.Chart);
     line1.XValues.DateTime = true;
     line1.DateTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
     cursorTool1.Series = line1;
     line1.Stairs = true;
     line1.XValues.DataMember = "SetTime";
     line1.YValues.DataMember = "Park Brk Pres Sw1";
     line1.DataSource = GetDataTable();

    tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
    tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelStyle.PointValue;
    tChart1.Export.Data.Excel.Save("C:\\Test1.xls");
    //Events
    tChart1.AfterDraw += new PaintChartEventHandler(tChart1_AfterDraw);
    cursorTool1.Change += new CursorChangeEventHandler(cursorTool1_Change);
    tChart1.Draw();
 }

//DataTable
 private DataTable GetDataTable()
 {
     DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable("DataSet");
     //Condition to filter
     //AddColumns in new Table
     DataColumn xval = new DataColumn("SetTime", typeof(DateTime));
     DataColumn yval = new DataColumn("Park Brk Pres Sw1", typeof(double));
     dataTable1.Columns.Add(xval);
     dataTable1.Columns.Add(yval);
     DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         DataRow newRow = dataTable1.NewRow();
         newRow[xval] = dt.AddSeconds(i * 5);
         newRow[yval] = 0;
         dataTable1.Rows.Add(newRow);
     }
     return dataTable1;
 }
//Calculate Interpolate point
 private double InterpolateLineSeries(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Custom series, int firstindex, int lastindex, double xvalue)
 {
     int index;
     for (index = firstindex; index <= lastindex; index++)
     {
         if (index == -1 || series.XValues.Value[index] > xvalue) break;
     }
     // safeguard
     if (index < 1) index = 1;
     else if (index >= series.Count) index = series.Count - 1;
     // y=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)+y1
     double dx = series.XValues[index] - series.XValues[index - 1];
     double dy = series.YValues[index] - series.YValues[index - 1];
     if (dx != 0.0) return dy * (xvalue - series.XValues[index - 1]) / dx + series.YValues[index - 1];
     else return 0.0;
 }

 private double InterpolateLineSeries(Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Custom series, double xvalue)
 {
     return InterpolateLineSeries(series, series.FirstVisibleIndex, series.LastVisibleIndex, xvalue);
 }
 private void cursorTool1_Change(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventArgs e)
 {
     xval = e.XValue;
     ann.Text = "";

    this.Text = e.ValueIndex.ToString();
    foreach (Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series s in tChart1.Series)
    {
        ann.Text += DateTime.FromOADate(s.XValues[e.ValueIndex]).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
 }
 private void tChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
 {
     int xs = tChart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(xval);
     int ys;
     g.Brush.Visible = true;
     g.Brush.Solid = true;
     for (int i = 0; i < tChart1.Series.Count; i++)

         if (tChart1.Series[i] is Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Custom)
         {
             ys = tChart1.Series[i].GetVertAxis.CalcYPosValue(InterpolateLineSeries(tChart1.Series[i] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Custom, xval));
             //Draw elipse above cursor tool.
             g.Brush.Color = tChart1.Series[i].Color;
             //Draw annotation as label above cursor tool.
             ann.Top = ys;
             ann.Left = xs;
         }
 }
```

Could you please, tell us if previous code help you to solve your problem?

I hope will helps.

Thanks,